# MoviePy preview showing besides screen blit

Tags: python, pygame, moviepy

I've got a problem.
I'm creating the Game Menu which i want to be:

1. background as video file (using MoviePy)
2. buttons on the video

The problem is video **is showing**, but the **button1** not.
Please help...

```
from moviepy.editor import *
import pygame
from pygame import mixer
import os
import cv2
print(os.getcwd())

# Initialization the PyGame
pygame.init()

# Create the screen
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)

# Menu Background
background = pygame.image.load('Assets/background.png')
button1 = pygame.image.load('Assets/button.png')


# Background SOUND
mixer.music.load('Assets/mainmenumusic.mp3')
mixer.music.set_volume(0.2)
mixer.music.play(-1)

# Game TITLE and ICON
pygame.display.set_caption("Game Launcher") # title of the game
icon = pygame.image.load('Assets/icon.png') # define the icon variable
pygame.display.set_icon(icon) # set the window icon to the icon variable

# FPS Lock
FPS = 60



clip = VideoFileClip('Assets/particles.mp4', audio=False)

# Game loop
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    WIN.blit(button1, (960, 540))
    clip.preview(fullscreen=True)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

The button is not showing because you blit it before the background video so the video covers it. You can just try with:

```
clip.preview(fullscreen=True)
WIN.blit(button1, (960, 540))
```